# R - Use same plotting function to each element in a list of dataframes and save resulting plots

Tags: r, list, dataframe, function, plot

I have this list of dataframes obtained from a Likert scale:

```
df1<-data.frame(A=c(1,2,2,3,4,5,1,1,2,3),
                B=c(4,4,2,3,4,2,1,5,2,2),
                C=c(3,3,3,3,4,2,5,1,2,3),
                D=c(1,2,5,5,5,4,5,5,2,3),
                E=c(1,4,2,3,4,2,5,1,2,3))
df1[colnames(df1)] <- lapply(df1[colnames(df1)], factor)


df2<-data.frame(A=c(1,2,2,3,4,5,1,1,2,3),
                B=c(4,4,2,3,4,2,1,5,2,2),
                C=c(3,3,3,3,4,2,5,1,2,3),
                D=c(1,2,5,5,5,4,5,5,2,3),
                E=c(1,4,2,3,4,2,5,1,2,3))
df2[colnames(df2)] <- lapply(df2[colnames(df2)], factor)


df3<-data.frame(A=c(1,2,2,1,4,5,3,1,2,3),
                B=c(3,4,1,3,4,1,3,5,2,2),
                C=c(3,3,1,3,3,2,5,1,2,3),
                D=c(3,1,5,5,5,1,5,5,2,3),
                E=c(3,1,2,3,4,2,5,3,2,1))
df3[colnames(df3)] <- lapply(df3[colnames(df3)], factor)


list<-list(df1,df2,df3)
```

And I have this function to make a Likert plot using the `likert` package:

```
install.packages("likert")
library(likert)

plot_likert <- function(data, title){plot(likert(reverse.levels(data)),
               type ="bar",center=3, group.order=names(data))+
               labs(x = "Theme", title=title, subtitle=paste("Number of observations:",nrow(data)))+ 
               guides(fill=guide_legend("Rank"))  
}
```

So that if I want to plot `df1` I just have to write

```
plot_likert(df1)
```

But how can I apply my `plot_likert` to `list` and send the resulting graph to an external folder? I tried to just run the function on the list but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you’ll want to use `lapply`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, how would you go about it? I'm quite new to R, sorry...

Comment: You could do something like `list_of_figures <- lapply(list, \(x) plot_likert(x, title = "title"))`. + There is a problem with `df3`